# How to fix httpclient tls unknow_certificate error?

Tags: java, ssl, httpclient

Our client communicates with server by using httpclient 4.5.2 and uses TLS 1.2 for end-to-end communication security.

At first,communication between client and server was smooth,but there was something wrong about communication between client and server recently. It seems to be caused due to some unknown certificate error during server hello of ssl handshaking which occurs sporadically.

I have checked certificates in client trust store and found the certificate from server. Then I opened ssl debug using `System.setProperty("javax.net.debug", "ssl");` and found that the certificate from server hello of ssl handshaking was not the right one which was loaded to my client trust store.

Subsequently,I used tcpdump to capture communication information between client and server and found that the certificate sent by server was the right one which was loaded to my client trust store but the certificate read by my client was wrong one. Strangely enough, I couldn't trace the origins of the wrong certificate. I've tried multiple variations of this, but none of them seem to work. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @Kavitha Karunakaran Thank you very much!

Comment: On what machine or where in the network did you do the tcpdump? What kind(s) of network are involved in your connection -- Internet, one LAN, multiple LANs? Personal/home or in a business or organization? If the latter, are there any security systems like IDS, IPS, WAF? On your (client) machine, especially if Windows, are there security features like antivirus, endpoint protection, device management, VPN? If you connect from a different machine in a different network location what cert do you get? Or another machine in the same network location?

Comment: We did the tcpdump on clinet machine and server machine,both Internet and LAN can appear this exception,we did the test in my company where there might be security systems like IDS, IPS, WAF,and there were security features like antivirus, endpoint protection, VPN on our (client) machine.In our test,some machines suffered from this exception, however the other  (client) machines didn't suffer from this exception which had the same network,os,security systems.@dave_thompson_085

Comment: So in each case does tcpdump on the client machine show different cert received than tcpdump on the server shows sent, and does tcpdump on the client machine show different cert received than the client _software_ sees? In the former case something is happening in your network(s) somewhere, and you need to find someone who knows about your network(s) and the devices connecting, routing, or managing them. In the latter case something is happening inside your client machine and you need to find someone who knows about that.